# "vendor VIB for HP found, but host is VMware"-error while installing VM

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I'll install ESXi in a virtual machine in VMware. But I've got this error:

[image]

The problem is not what is this meaning but how can I solve it? Must I download a new iso file from VMware that is not coming from HP or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'll install ESXi in a virtual machine in VMware.

You can solve it by not installing in in vmware player.

That sounds rash, but ESXi is not an OS. It is a bare type-1 hypervisor. It is not a full OS to install in vmware-player.  Instead it will replace your old windows+vmware-player (or any other OS) and install the ESXi-OS.